# How to work with foldRight() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I try this code

```
        println(listOf(1, 2, 4).foldRight(0) { total, next ->
            total - next
        })
```

I thought it works like 0 + 4 - 2 - 1 = 1.
But it returns 3. Why?
Sorry for this silly question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

foldRight works by accumulating the result from right to left. In your case, it is going to do

(1 - (2 - (4 - 0))) = (1 - (2 - 4)) = 1 - (-2) = 3

Note that your operation has its parameters in the wrong order, foldRight will pass you the next element as the first parameter and the accumulator as the second parameter. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-right.html. If you swap them, you would have

(((0 - 4) - 2) - 1) = - 7

unless I am getting something wrong